# click anywhere on the screen to remove class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several drop-down menus where i have added an add and remove class when the button is selected

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/newkidontheblock/7owwvecd/26/)

I would like to do a small function to this so when the user click anywhere on the screen the class is removed ...

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var $pane = $(this).closest('.btn-container').find('.pane');
    if ($pane.hasClass('inactive')) {
        $('.btn-container .pane').addClass('inactive');
        $pane.removeClass('inactive');
    } else {
        $pane.addClass('inactive');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your logic binding click event to `document` and using following logic to toggle the `inactive` class:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  var $pane = $(e.target).closest('.btn-container').find('.pane');
  $pane.add($('.pane:not(.inactive)')).toggleClass('inactive');
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
here
<div class="btn-container menu small-4 medium-2">
  <a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans">sector</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <article class="pane inactive">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </article>
  <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
</div>
<!-- BTN CONTAINER ENDS HERE  -->


<div class="btn-container menu small-4 medium-2">
  <a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans">products</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <article class="pane inactive">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>Menu 1</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>Menu 1</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>Menu 1</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>Menu 1</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </article>
  <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
</div>
<!-- BTN CONTAINER ENDS HERE  -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a click handler to the document object to add the inactive class

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var $pane = $(this).closest('.btn-container').find('.pane')
  $pane.toggleClass('inactive');
  if (!$pane.hasClass('inactive')) {
    $('.btn-container .pane:not(.inactive)').not($pane).addClass('inactive');
  }
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.btn').length) {
    $('.btn-container .pane:not(.inactive)').addClass('inactive');
  }
})
```

```css
.inactive {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
here
<div class="btn-container menu small-4 medium-2">
  <a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans">sector</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <article class="pane inactive">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </article> <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
</div> <!-- BTN CONTAINER ENDS HERE  -->


<div class="btn-container menu small-4 medium-2">
  <a class="inline-block btn no-text-trans">products</a>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
  <article class="pane inactive">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 1</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 1</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 1</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><p>Menu 1</p></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </article> <!-- PANE ENDS HERE -->
</div> <!-- BTN CONTAINER ENDS HERE  -->
```